# Sending vital security values to my github

Tags: android, security, github

accidentally I have send android.keystore with commit to my github.
How to undo this to not leave any trace.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will remove your pushed commits

```
git reset --hard 'xxxxx'

git clean -f -d

git push -f
```

Comment: it's the commit-id

Comment: @chrischris Please accept the answer,  if your problem is soled by provided solution.